# Getting xsession-errors after Unity Lens install

Tags: unity, applications-lens

I apologize in advance if I am leaving something out here. Please let me know what additional info is required,  and i will be happy to post it.

Can you tell me what these error messages are, and how I can go about resolving them?

```
WARN  2012-02-02 14:02:56 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /net/launchpad/lens/utilities does not exist
WARN  2012-02-02 14:02:56 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /net/launchpad/lens/utilities does not exist
WARN  2012-02-02 14:02:56 unity.iconloader IconLoader.cpp:509 Unable to load contents of file:///usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/places/svg/category-installed.svg: Error opening file: No such file or directory
WARN  2012-02-02 14:02:56 unity.iconloader IconLoader.cpp:509 Unable to load contents of file:///usr/share/icons/unity-icon-theme/places/svg/category-available.svg: Error opening file: No such file or directory
WARN  2012-02-02 14:02:56 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method InfoRequest proxy /net/launchpad/lens/askubuntu does not exist
WARN  2012-02-02 14:02:56 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:255 Cannot call method SetActive proxy /net/launchpad/lens/askubuntu does not exist
```

I am also getting Nautilus errors logged here. I do not remember what lenses I installed, or from where (Software Center, manual install, etc).

Comment: Are you experiencing any negative symptoms besides the logged errors?

Comment: Yes, getting a lot of Nautilus errors as well.

Comment: I don't recall the source- you have a recommended one, perhaps?

Comment: What *kind* of errors? Just lines in a log file, or are you experiencing problems?

Comment: To differentiate, the Nautilus errors have been happening since I did a fresh install of 11.10 last week, including updates.

Comment: I did not post the Nautilus errors as of yet- my research here indicates there might be a bug in the release- saw some postings on the 64-bit version regarding that.

Comment: Do you need entire contents of the xsession-errors.log?

Comment: Please describe what is happening on your desktop that you don't like (INDEPENDENT of log files) and what you expect to be happening. .xsession-errors happen all the time for no real reason.

Comment: Jacob, my apologies again, it seems I've wasted your time. I did not consider it normal that the log file was filling up with Nautilus error messages every time I moved a application window on the desktop. That said, you state that this is normal, so I guess that's that.

Comment: As to the Lens question (this posting), all I needed was a suggestion on how to resolve the missing file errors- perhaps I use the recommended (yours) source to get the complete package- issue solved?? Just provide that, and I promise to leave you alone:)

Comment: Do I need to repost this, and revise? I can't seem to close it, and haven't gotten a relevant answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell all those are mostly harmless.  The call method errors happen to me every time as well, but the scopes/lenses are still working.  I suspect they just take a bit to start.  The missing icons are interesting and I've been trying to track that one down without any success.  However, the dash looks fine to me, including icons.

So in summary, I think this is all safe to ignore.  The missing icons might be a bug and I will file it as soon as I can figure out what's going on in more details.

Edit: bug filed for the missing icons: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-lens-applications/+bug/932212

I hope to post a patch to it today.

Comment: In a word- <awesome> and thank you! As far as I could tell, the lens(es) referenced in the .xsession-errors log appeared to be functioning correctly- at least the ones I know how to access and use so far. Just to be sure, I went back and checked in Synaptic PM that the relevant packages were installed, and marked them for re-installation, but no change. Your feedback on this issue was greatly appreciated.